# Xamarin Forms entry tap does not bring up keyboard for entire width

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using a grid with nested grids to render a form.  For some of the entries, I can tap on any area in the entry and it brings up the keyboard. For others, I have to tap on the left side to bring up the keyboard, as shown on the yellow highlighted entry in the image. I've tried placing the grids as children of a stacklayout instead, changing the keyboard type to not be numeric, set horizontal options, set width request.  The only thing that works is when I put the nested grid in its own parent with no other children.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to avoid setting a tap gesture recognizer for the whole grid.[image]

Here's my code:

```
  <Grid Padding="3,20,10,20"  VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- purchase price-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Purchase Price:" />
                                <Entry Grid.Column="1" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center"  x:Name="purchasePrice" Text="{Binding SalesPrice}"   ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--- address-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Address:" />
                                <Entry Grid.Column="1"  VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="address1" Text="{Binding Address}"   ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--- city-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="City:" />
                                <!--<Picker Grid.Column="1" x:Name="cityPicker"></Picker>-->
                                <autocomplete:SfAutoComplete VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="40" x:Name="cityAutoComplete" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!-- county -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="County:" />
                                <Picker Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="countyPicker"></Picker>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!-- loan -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="4">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Loan:" />
                                <cb:Checkbox Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="isLoanCheckbox"   HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Checked="{Binding HasLoan}"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                </cb:Checkbox>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--down payment -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Down Payment:" />
                                <Entry Grid.Column="1" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="downPayment" Text="{Binding DownPayment}"   ></Entry>

                                <Grid  Grid.Column="2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <!--<Label TextColor="Gray" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Grid.Column="0"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Small"
                                    Text="{ x:Static local:FontAwesomeFont.Dollar }">

                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Dollar_Tapped" />
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label.FontFamily>
                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="fontawesome-webfont.ttf#FontAwesome" iOS="FontAwesome" />
                                        </Label.FontFamily>
                                    </Label>

                                    <Label TextColor="Gray" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Grid.Column="1"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Small"
                                Text="{ x:Static local:FontAwesomeFont.Percent }">

                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Percent_Tapped" />
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label.FontFamily>
                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="fontawesome-webfont.ttf#FontAwesome" iOS="FontAwesome" />
                                        </Label.FontFamily>
                                    </Label>-->
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--interest rate  -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="6">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Interest Rate:" />
                                <Entry  Grid.Column="1" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center"  x:Name="interestRate"  Text="{Binding InterestRate}"  ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--term  -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="7">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Term:" />
                                <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center"  x:Name="term"  Text="{Binding Term}"  ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!-- misc fees  -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="8">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Misc Fees:" />
                                <Entry Grid.Column="1" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center"  x:Name="miscFees"  Text="{Binding MiscFeesTotal}"  ></Entry>
                                <Label TextColor="Gray" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,-10,5,0"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Large"
                        Text="{ x:Static local:IonicIconsFont.GearA }">

                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MiscFees_Tapped" />
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="ionicons.ttf#ionicons" iOS="Ionicons" />
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--closing credits  -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="9">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Closing Credits:" />
                                <Entry Grid.Column="1" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="closingCreditsTotalEntry" Text="{Binding ClosingCreditsTotal}" ></Entry>
                                <Label TextColor="Gray" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,-10,5,0"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Large"
                        Text="{ x:Static local:IonicIconsFont.GearA }">

                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ColsingCredits_Tapped" />
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="ionicons.ttf#ionicons" iOS="Ionicons" />
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--hazard  -->
                        <Grid  Grid.Row="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Hazard Ins:" />
                                <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="hazard"  Text="{Binding HazardInsurance}"  ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--prpp tax  -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="11">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Ann Prop. Tax:" />
                                <Entry Grid.Row="0" Keyboard="Numeric" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalOptions="Center"  x:Name="propTax"  Text="{Binding AnnualPropertyTax}"  ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--tax proration-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="12">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Tax Proration:" />
                                <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center"  x:Name="taxProration"  Text="{Binding TaxProration}"  ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--city trans tax (auto calc)-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="13">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="City Tran Tax:" />
                                <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="transTax"  Text="{Binding CityTransferTax}"  ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--monthly hoa-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="14">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Monthly HOA:" />
                                <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center"   x:Name="hoa"  Text="{Binding MonthlyHOA}"  ></Entry>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--closing date-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="15">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Closing Date:" />
                                <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="ClosingDatePicker"></DatePicker>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                        <!--attorney-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="16">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label  Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Attorney:" />
                                <Picker Grid.Column="1" x:Name="attorneyPicker"></Picker>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

**Removing a parent AbsoluteLayout Solved the issue.**

I faced this one before now apparently it happens because your layout's options are not set to expand what I did to fix it was something like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpamd" TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }" FontSize="Small" Text="Purchase Price:" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpamd" />
                            <Entry Grid.Column="1" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  x:Name="purchasePrice" Text="{Binding SalesPrice}"   ></Entry>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, that sets me in the right direction , but unfortunately did not work

Comment: Can you try setting both options to fill and expand for the entry and let me know? Whether it works or not

Comment: Why are you using nested grid though why don't you have a parent stacklayout and then a series of grid's?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too.  Didn't seem to work unless I had that particular grid with the entry as the only child in a parent whether that parent be a grid or stack layout.  Its very strange as some of the other entries are not like this

Comment: Is it that only one entry is not working or all of them have this issue?

Comment: the downpayment entry is the last one that works. There are others above downpayment that work as well.  All others below do not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185705/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-patrick-goode).